# how to filter an array of objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following array of objects

```
{
  : items=>[
    {
      : id=>"cam-id-1",
      : translations=>[
        {
          : name=>"abcd",
          : description=>"geiajfe",
          : locale=>: fr,
          : createdAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00,
          : updatedAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00
        },
        {
          : name=>"bon jor",
          : description=>"jwi nifneaoin ofieafi",
          : locale=>: de,
          : createdAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00,
          : updatedAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00
        },
        {
          : name=>"hello",
          : description=>"hello abcd",
          : locale=>: en,
          : createdAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00,
          : updatedAt=>Fri,
          27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      : id=>"cam-id-2",
      : translations=>[

      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

I want to filter the translations array based on locale. so e.g if i pass locale = fr then return the whole object but only one object in translations since there's only one locale fr.

so the output will be

```
 {
      : items=>[
        {
          : id=>"cam-id-1",
          : translations=>[
            {
              : name=>"abcd",
              : description=>"geiajfe",
              : locale=>: fr,
              : createdAt=>Fri,
              27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00,
              : updatedAt=>Fri,
              27Jul201800: 00: 00UTC+00: 00
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          : id=>"cam-id-2",
          : translations=>[

          ]
        }
      ],
    }
```

i created a method to filter translations but it just returns filtered translation and i dont think this is the right way.

```
  def filter_translations(test)
    array = []
    test[:items][0][:translations].each do |t|
      array << t if t[:locale].to_s.casecmp(locale.to_s).zero? || t[:locale].to_s.include?(locale.to_s)
    end
    array
  end
```

any idea?

Comment: The space after each colon raises a syntax error. Please remove those space so that readers who wish to cut and paste your code don't have to do it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

To get just a single thing from a list, use [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first).

```
# {:name=>"abcd", :description=>"geiajfe", :locale=>:fr}
translation_fr = item.fetch(:translations).first { |translation|
  translation[:locale] == :fr
}
```

To get this for all items, wrap it in a [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
# [ {:name=>"abcd", :description=>"geiajfe", :locale=>:fr}, ... ]
items_fr = test.fetch(:items).map { |item|
  item.fetch(:translations).first { |translation|
    translation[:locale] == :fr
  }
}
```

---

To return the item + the chosen translation, you can return this from the `map`. But you need to be careful, `item` is not a copy. If you alter it in the `map` you alter it in `tests`.

For example...

```
items_fr = test.fetch(:items).map { |item|
  translation = item.fetch(:translations).first { |translation|
    translation[:locale] == :fr
  }
  item[:translations] = [translation]
  item
}
```

This will return what you want.

```
{:id=>"cam-id-1", :translations=>[{:name=>"abcd", :description=>"geiajfe", :locale=>:fr}]}
```

But it will also alter the items in `test`, they're the same objects. Instead you need to return a copy of each `item`. You can call `item = item.clone` and change the key, or you can use [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) in one step.

```
items_fr = test.fetch(:items).map { |item|
  translation = item.fetch(:translations).first { |translation|
    translation[:locale] == :fr
  }
  item.merge translations: [translation]
}
```

Rather than altering `item[:translations]`, I'd recommend you add a new `translation` key for your chosen translation.

```
# [ {:id=>"cam-id-1", :translations=>[{:name=>"abcd", :description=>"geiajfe", :locale=>:fr}, {:name=>"bon jor", :description=>"jwi nifneaoin ofieafi", :locale=>:de}, {:name=>"hello", :description=>"hello abcd", :locale=>:en}], :translation=>{:name=>"abcd", :description=>"geiajfe", :locale=>:fr}} ]
items_fr = test.fetch(:items).map { |item|
  translation = item.fetch(:translations).first { |translation|
    translation[:locale] == :fr
  }
  item[:translation] = translation
  item
}
```

Now you can repeat this process to pick a new translation if necessary.

---

You can improve this process in a few ways. First, if possible, change the `translation` array to a hash keyed on locale for faster lookup. Second, get everything into objects which encapsulates the details and allows for more complex behavior.

```
class Translations
  attr_accessor :translations

  def initialize
    @translations = {}
  end

  # Get the translation for a locale
  def for_locale(locale)
    translations.fetch(locale)
  end

  # Add a translation for a locale
  def add_translation(translation)
    translations[translation.locale] = translation
  end

  # Import translations from an array. Reorganize
  # them as a hash keyed on locale.
  def import_from_array(translations)
    translations.each do |import_translation|
      add_translation Translation.new(import_translation)
    end
  end
end

class Translation
  attr_accessor :name, :description, :locale

  def initialize(name:, description:, locale:)
    @name = name
    @description = description
    @locale = locale
  end
end

class Item
  attr_accessor :translations, :translation, :id

  def initialize
    @translations ||= Translations.new
  end

  def pick_translation(locale)
    @translation = translations.for_locale(locale)
  end

  def import_from_hash(**args)
    @id = args.fetch(:id)
    translations.import_from_array( args.fetch(:translations) )
  end
end

items = test.fetch(:items).map do |import|
  # parse
  item = Item.new.import_from_hash(import)
  # pick a translation
  item.pick_translation(:fr)
  # return the object
  item
end
```

For example, if these translations are repeated and the copies are taking up memory you could leverage the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Rather than each Item having its own copy, they could share the same Translation objects.

---

I've used [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) rather than `[]` so it will throw a `KeyError` exception if the required keys are missing.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern so map will return me all items matching locale but i want to get whole items array with items in translations matching locale. sorry if i was not clear in my question. Please check the output i am expecting.

Comment: @User7354632781 I see. I've added that code in, plus how to reorganize this into objects.